# ¿Cómo redireccionar todas las páginas de una web a un subdominio para móviles?

Tags: linux, web, .htaccess, apache2, cms

Actualmente detecto si los que acceden a la web son dispositivos móviles/tablets y los redirijo sin problemas al subdominio "m.loquesea.com" si acceden a "www.loquesea.com"  o "loquesea.com".

El problema es que si acceden a "www.loquesea.com/aplicacion-web-increible/" no se redirige a "m.loquesea.com/aplicacion-web-increible/"

La ruta es la misma tanto en versión móviles como para ordenadores.

¿Alguna idea? **Gracias**

Comment: Debes detectar en cada una de las paginas a las que se puede acceder sí es un movil en el que se está navegando y que haga la redirección

Comment: ¿Cómo lo hago? ¿Algún enlace de interés? Sólo encuentro ejemplos de lo que tengo hecho yo por la web. Gracias

Comment: Revisalo a ver sí te sirve [REDIRECCIONAR A VERSIÓN MÓVIL CON HTACCESS](https://www.carlestrujillodiaz.info/redireccionar-a-version-movil-con-htaccess/)